# React Render Array of object in parent-child realationship with checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to render the object of array in parent and child relationship tree structure with checkbox to select any of the child or parent to do some operation in react

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and if possible share your example on stackblitz or codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sandbox where I built what I thought you meant. You can see the autcome here: https://5dhss.csb.app/

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const objectOfArrays = {
  manfred: ["kreuz", 12, "abc"],
  dieter: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8],
  robert: ["bar", "321", "foo"]
};

export default function App() {
  const [{ row, key }, setSelected] = useState({ row: -1, key: null });

  const keys = Object.keys(objectOfArrays);

  const rowNumbers = keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < objectOfArrays[key].length; j += 1) {
      if (!acc.includes(j)) acc = [...acc, j];
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        {row < 0 ? (
          <>Click into a field</>
        ) : (
          <>
            You selected [{row}, {key}]
          </>
        )}
      </p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {keys.map(key => {
              return <th key={key}>{key}</th>;
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rowNumbers.map(row => (
            <tr key={row}>
              {keys.map(key => (
                <td
                  key={key}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelected({ key, row });
                  }}
                >
                  {objectOfArrays[key][row]}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```